# Getting a page with jQuery .get - Google Chrome Extentions

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Google Chrome extension. I've done this before, anyway I'm trying to load a page and HTML from the page. Not trying ot display it, just trying to get a div's contents on the page.

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $.get('http://learntc.net', function(data) {
     var hatid = $(data).find('#ctl00_ctl00_cphRoblox_cphMyRobloxContent_txtStatusMessage');
    alert('Load was performed.');
    });
});
```

*This, works. When I decide to to change the URL to http://www.roblox.com/my/home.aspx?ID=1 it breaks. This is the URL I'm trying to get data from.*

I keep getting this error when I click the link though: **Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:** Followed by the pages source.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error is coming from jQuery?

Comment: It works on like every page but, roblox.com?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, jQuery and JavaScript allow you to use .get() function only within the same domain. So if you change it to other domain, the code will not work.

Comment: Not with Google Chrome Extensions. I don't know why, but it works.